# How do I access a servlet when using JQuery

Tags: jquery, jsp, servlets, jqtouch

I am using JQTouch, on top of JQuery, within jsp pages.  I am using a form to send data to a Servlet.  (See example below)  I want to send params to the server.

But on server side I have a breakpoint which is never reached.

```
    function submitForm(val) { if(!formSubmitted) {
        formSubmitted = true;
       if(document.layers) {
          document.forms[0].action.value = val;
          document.forms[0].submit();
       }
       else {
          document.forms[0].action.value = val;
          document.forms[0].submit();
       }
    }
  }  <div>
        <div class="toolbar">
            <h1>Shows</h1>
            <a class="back" href="#home">Back</a>
        </div>
        <form id="myform" action="/servlet/LDPhoneShowServlet" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value=""> 
            <ul class="rounded">
            <li class="arrow">
    <a class="submit" onclick="submitForm('selectboothshow_<%=show.getETSHID()%>');return false;" href="#" ><%=show.getShowName()%></a>
              </li>
            </ul>
        </form>
```

In other pages, I have used below...which works.

```
<form  id="myform" action="/servlet/LoginServlet" method="POST" class="form" >
    <div class="toolbar"><h1>Login</h1></div>
         <input type="hidden" name="action" value="">
          <input type="hidden" name="obtain" value="">
          <input type="hidden" name="UserName" value="">
          <ul class="rounded">
                 <li><input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="login" ></li>
                 <li><input  type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"></li>
          </ul>
          <a style="margin:0 10px;color:rgba(0,0,0,.9)" href="#" class="submit whiteButton">Submit</a>
  </form>
```

Where is my mistake?  Am I using the JQuery framework incorrectly?  Can you not use an < li> to access a Servlet?  I don't believe that I can use the submit() function, as I need to pass the arguments.

Thanks.

Comment: I must say that all of my Java code worked BEFORE I added the JQTouch framework. I don't believe that my problems have anything to do with my original application. As soon as I remove references to JQtouch, the application goes back to the way it used to work. I am still not sure, but I think the JQTouch code hijacks the onclick event. Does anyone know JTouch well enough to explain how I can update a value on the page using the onclick event, and still be able to pass that to the Servlet.  All my parameters come up null.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see any `<script>` tags - maybe that's your problem.

Comment: I left them out, because I could not seem to get the code on this page formatted correctly...my fault.  They are in the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Check the action URL. Does it really point to your servlet? It seems, you are missing the webapp name.

Comment: Yes, as I said before, the second example works, and it points to a servlet in a common location.

Answer (score 0):

Your web.xml file should looks like:

```
<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>my.servlet.Class</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/LoginServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

your form tag, in this case, must be

```
<form  id="myform" action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/LoginServlet" method="POST" class="form" >
    <div class="toolbar"><h1>Login</h1></div>
         <input type="hidden" name="action" value="">
          <input type="hidden" name="obtain" value="">
          <input type="hidden" name="UserName" value="">
          <ul class="rounded">
                 <li><input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="login" ></li>
                 <li><input  type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"></li>
          </ul>
          <a style="margin:0 10px;color:rgba(0,0,0,.9)" href="#" class="submit whiteButton">Submit</a>
  </form>
```

Comment: I must say that all of my Java code worked **BEFORE** I added the JQTouch framework.  I don't believe that my problems have anything to do with my original application. As soon as I remove references to JQtouch, the application goes back to the way it used to work.  I am still not sure, but I think the JQTouch code hijacks the onclick event.  Does anyone know JTouch well enough to explain how I can update a value on the page using the onclick event?